# Use normal PHP libraries in CodeIgniter

Tags: api, codeigniter, tumblr

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I'm trying to use the [Tumblr php library](http://codehero.co/como-instalar-y-configurar-chef/); however I'm not sure how can I adapt it to work with CodeIgniter (if such thing is possible).

I managed to find a few Tumblr CI libraries but they don't provide all the methods available (like tag searching), and the [most advanced by BIOSTALL](https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Tumblr-API) only supports the v1 of the Tumblr API.

Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do these steps:

1. Download Tumblr API library for CodeIgniter [here](https://github.com/jmahoney127/Codeigniter-Tumblr-APIv2-Library)
2. tumblr.php (in config folder) put on your config folder
3. Change the config file with your parameters:

   > ```
   > $config['tumblr_consumer_key']            = '';
   > $config['tumblr_secret_key']          = '';
   > $config['tumblr_url']                 = 'good.tumblr.com';
   > $config['callback_url']                   = 'controller/method';
   > $config['auth_callback']              = 'controller/method';
   > ```
4. Tumblr.php (in library folder) put on your library folder
5. OAuth.php (in third_party folder) put on your third_party (create if didn't exist).
6. Use it. For example:

> ```
> $this->load->library('Tumblr');
> $blog_info = $this->tumblr->blog_info();
> // Blog info returned in object
> echo $blog_info->title; // echo blog title
> ```

Comment: I checked that one out also, but I'm not sure how the procedure to make a proper authenticated request is made.

Comment: never mind, I managed to edit the library code to make it suit my needs, thank you